# Подключение драйвера PSQL Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qtcreator, psql

**Имеется**:

1.Windows 7 64bit;

2.PostgreSQL 9.5 32bit;

3.Qt Creator 4.5;

4.Qt lib 5.10.0;

5.MinGW 5.3.0 32bit

**Задача**: подключить драйвер PSQL к проекту на Qt.

Испробовал уже все способы, выводящиеся по запросу "qt build postgresql driver". 
Драйвер все равно не собирается.

Большинство источников советует собирать этим способом:
`qmake"INCLUDEPATH+=C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\include""LIBS+="C:\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib\libpq.lib" psql.pro
mingw32-make`

Получаю такую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка после выполнения mingw32-make]

Вывод консоли при запуске проекта:

`Available drivers: ("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded`

.pro файл:

```
QT -= gui
QT += sql
QT += core

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <iostream>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSql>
#include <QtSql>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL7");
    db.setHostName("188.120.232.***");
    db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("123");
    if (!db.open()) {
        cout«"Crash "«endl;
    }
    else
        cout«"Ok"«endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как получилось победить?

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось решить закинув в папку 
{Путь до Qt}Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
файл libpq.dll

Только тот dll что лежал в папке установленного PostreSql не подошел, пришлось по [вот этой статье](http://easy-qt.blogspot.ru/2012/10/postgresql-qt-windows-mingw.html) скомпилировать все библиотеки и оттуда взять libpq.dll

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот это видео [Компиляция драйвера для СУБД PostgreSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2o9IKLmY7U&t=12s). Может тебе поможет.